# Trying to get SUM of ListBox selected items from local DataTable into a Label

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2015

I have been searching for days, for any possible reference or suggestions and everything I've come across hasn't worked.

**The goal:**

User will select options in ComboBox1 that will then determine the available options in ComboBox2, then will populate a list of operations in ListBox1.

When the user selects available operations in ListBox1, I need the output to be the sum of values (total time in minutes in this case) into a label for display.

The data used in stored in a local db. So far everything works with my comboboxes and the listbox.

Im attempting to get the Text value, of all selected items, in ListBox1 to output the numeric value in my table (column 4 "OperationsTime"), into a label that will display the sum of all the selections (Total Time In Minutes).

**Some Things I have Tried From Other Posts:**

1. ```
    Label9.Text = ListBox1.ValueMember
   ```
2. ```
    Label9.Text = ListBox1.ValueMember.ToString
   ```
3. ```
    Label9.Text = CType(ListBox1.SelectedItem, DataRowView).Row.Item("OperationsTime").ToString
   ```

Attempted using Double:

```
         Dim Total As Double = 0
    For Each Time As Integer In ListBox1.SelectedItems
        Total += CDbl(Time.ToString.Substring(Time.ToString.LastIndexOf(",") + 1))
    Next
    Label9.Text = Total.ToString
```

**Screen Shot of the Table:**
[Operations Data Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bDuAi.jpg)

**Below is my code:**

```
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Configuration
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Public Class MainHome
    Private Function GetData(ByVal sql As String) As DataTable
        Dim constr As String = "Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\hartj\Documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\TIMEMATRIX2.0\TIMEMATRIX2.0\TMX.mdf;Integrated Security=True"
        Using con As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(constr)
            Using sda As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(sql, con)
                Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable()
                sda.Fill(dt)
                Dim row As DataRow = dt.NewRow()
                row(0) = 1
                row(1) = "Please Select"
                dt.Rows.InsertAt(row, 0)
                Return dt
            End Using
        End Using
    End Function

    Private Sub MainHome_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        ComboBox1.DataSource = Me.GetData("SELECT  SizeId, SizeName FROM Size")
        ComboBox1.DisplayMember = "SizeName"
        ComboBox1.ValueMember = "SizeId"
        ComboBox2.Enabled = False
        ComboBox3.Enabled = False
    End Sub

    Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectionChangeCommitted(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectionChangeCommitted
        ComboBox2.DataSource = Nothing
        ComboBox3.DataSource = Nothing
        ComboBox2.Enabled = False
        ComboBox3.Enabled = False
        If ComboBox1.SelectedValue.ToString() <> "0" Then
            Dim sql As String = String.Format("SELECT DetailLevelId, DetailLevelName FROM DetailLevel WHERE SizeId = {0}", ComboBox1.SelectedValue)
            ComboBox2.DataSource = Me.GetData(sql)
            ComboBox2.DisplayMember = "DetailLevelName"
            ComboBox2.ValueMember = "DetailLevelId"
            ComboBox2.Enabled = True
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub ComboBox2_SelectionChangeCommitted(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox2.SelectionChangeCommitted
        ListBox1.DataSource = Nothing
        ListBox1.Enabled = False
        If ComboBox2.SelectedValue.ToString() <> "0" Then
            Dim sql As String = String.Format("SELECT OperationsId, OperationsName, OperationsTime FROM Operations WHERE DetailLevelId = {0}", ComboBox2.SelectedValue)
            ListBox1.DataSource = Me.GetData(sql)
            ListBox1.ValueMember = "OperationsName"
            ListBox1.ValueMember = "OperationsTime"
            ListBox1.Enabled = True

            Label9.Text = CType(ListBox1.SelectedValue, Integer).ToString
            'Label.Text = CType(cbbank.SelectedItem, DataRowView).Row.Item("Account").ToString
        End IF
    End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for the edits/corrections to the main post! I apologize for the disorganized post.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim totalOperationsTime As Double

For Each view As DataRowView In ListBox1.SelectedItems
    totalOperationsTime += CDbl(view("OperationsTime"))
Next
```

There's no need to get the `DataRow` from the `DataRowView` because you can access the field values directly from the `DataRowView`.  It can and does do many of the same things that the `DataRow` does.

That's the most conventional way but there are other options too.  You could throw some LINQ at it:

```
Dim totalOperationsTime = ListBox1.SelectedItems.Cast(Of DataRowView)().
                                                 Sum(Function(view) CDbl(view("OperationsTime")))
```

It is somewhat annoying that the `ValueMember` property only helps you get a value for the `SelectedItem`.  Here's a class I wrote some time ago that adds a `GetItemValue` method that makes use of the `ValueMember` much as the `GetItemText` method does for the `DisplayMember`:

```
Public Class ListBoxEx
    Inherits ListBox

    Public Function GetItemValue(item As Object) As Object
        Dim index = Me.Items.IndexOf(item)

        If (index <> -1 AndAlso Me.DataManager IsNot Nothing) Then
            Return Me.FilterItemOnProperty(Me.DataManager.List(index), Me.ValueMember)
        End If

        Return Nothing
    End Function

End Class
```

If you use that control instead of a regular `ListBox` then you can do this:

```
Dim totalOperationsTime As Double

For Each item In ListBoxEx1.SelectedItems
    totalOperationsTime += CDbl(ListBoxEx1.GetItemValue(item))
Next
```

or this:

```
Dim totalOperationsTime = ListBox1.SelectedItems.Cast(Of Object)().
                                                 Sum(Function(item) CDbl(ListBoxEx1.GetItemValue(item)))
```

One advantage of using that custom control is that you don't have to know what type the data source or its items are.  You only have to know that the `ValueMember` has been set.

Comment: Thank you! I will try this now and post results.

Answer (score 0):

I made a few changes to your code. It works with a ListBox. See comments for details.

```
' "Please Select" doesn't work well in the ListBox, I added it as an option
Private Shared Function GetData(ByVal sql As String, insertPleaseSelect As Boolean) As DataTable
    Dim constr As String = "Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\hartj\Documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\TIMEMATRIX2.0\TIMEMATRIX2.0\TMX.mdf;Integrated Security=True"
    Using con As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(constr)
        Using sda As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(sql, con)
            Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable()
            sda.Fill(dt)
            If insertPleaseSelect Then
                Dim row As DataRow = dt.NewRow()
                row(0) = 1
                row(1) = "Please Select"
                dt.Rows.InsertAt(row, 0)
            End If
            Return dt
        End Using
    End Using
End Function

Private Sub MainHome_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    ComboBox1.DataSource = GetData("SELECT  [SizeId], [SizeName] FROM [Size]", True)
    ComboBox1.DisplayMember = "SizeName"
    ComboBox1.ValueMember = "SizeId"
    ComboBox2.Enabled = False
    ListBox1.SelectionMode = SelectionMode.MultiSimple ' allow multi-select
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectionChangeCommitted(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectionChangeCommitted
    ComboBox2.DataSource = Nothing
    ComboBox2.Enabled = False
    If ComboBox1.SelectedValue.ToString() <> "0" Then
        Dim sql As String = String.Format("SELECT [DetailLevelId], [DetailLevelName] FROM [DetailLevel] WHERE [SizeId] = {0}", ComboBox1.SelectedValue)
        ComboBox2.DataSource = GetData(sql, True)
        ComboBox2.DisplayMember = "DetailLevelName"
        ComboBox2.ValueMember = "DetailLevelId"
        ComboBox2.Enabled = True
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox2_SelectionChangeCommitted(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox2.SelectionChangeCommitted
    ListBox1.DataSource = Nothing
    ListBox1.Enabled = False
    If ComboBox2.SelectedValue.ToString() <> "0" Then
        Dim sql As String = String.Format("SELECT [OperationsId], [OperationsName], [OperationsTime] FROM [Operations] WHERE [DetailLevelId] = {0}", ComboBox2.SelectedValue)
        ListBox1.DataSource = GetData(sql, False)
        ListBox1.DisplayMember = "OperationsName" ' changed this from ValueMember to DisplayMember
        ListBox1.ValueMember = "OperationsTime"
        ListBox1.Enabled = True
        ListBox1.ClearSelected() ' Every time the ListBox is populated, clear it
    End If
End Sub

' Added this handler to respond to user input, not programmatic selection changes
Private Sub ListBox1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ListBox1.Click
    ' Here is the sum
    Label9.Text = ListBox1.SelectedItems.OfType(Of DataRowView).Sum(Function(o) CType(o("OperationsTime"), Double))
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you! Only issue im having is it throws an exception "An OLE DB Provider was not specified in the ConnectionString.  An example would be, 'Provider=SQLOLEDB;'"

Comment: Should I change the connecting string to "SQLOLEDB" ?

Comment: Sorry, that was left over from my testing. You should use the same provider you used before. I was testing on an Access db.

Comment: Boom! Works like charm! Question, is it best to clear selections ("Listbox1.ClearSelected") for these scenarios? Only time ive used the clear function was for the user to clear items to make changes.

Comment: @Intelligent_Meathead great! It depends on how you want it to work. It felt better to me when changing the items in the ListBox for the selection to be cleared, because there was one selected by default (and the _click handler wasn't being fired so it was kind of an unknown state)

Comment: Also, I'd like to add 3 more labels. 1 label that takes the total minutes and shows "Total hours", 1 label that then shows "Total Days" and the the last label that shows "Total Oven Time" in hours when the user selects the operations "CURE/OVEN" or "POST CURE/OVEN". What would be the best method for these?

Comment: `ListBox1.SelectedItems.OfType(Of DataRowView).Sum(Function(o) CType(o("OperationsTime"), Double))` replace "OperationsTime" with the desired field.

Comment: "OperationsTime" is a column in the database. Will changing it to an item in the "OperationsName" column work?

Comment: I assume OperationsName is not a Double, so no it would fail when it is cast. You have a text query where that filtering can be done. Or you could also do it in LINQ. Without testing it, I guess something like this should work `Dim postCureOvenSum = ListBox1.SelectedItems.OfType(Of DataRowView).Where(Function(o) o("OperationsName").ToString() = "POST CURE/OVEN").Sum(Function(o) CType(o("OperationsTime"), Double))`

Comment: This may work for you, but FWIW I dislike storing and retrieving the data in the UI control. Ideally the data is in an object behind the scenes and the UI is only used for user input and display. My solution violates that. But your code is so far down that path that I chose not to overhaul it.

Comment: I appreciate all your help! I have a lot to learn to say the least. Your last answer looks like it would solve things for the Oven Times but the .Where is giving me "Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'Where' accepts this number of arguments."

Comment: hmm... did you paste the entire line I put in my comment? It works on my end.

Comment: Sorry, it does work! All i need to finish this now is to format the values somehow into hours. The current vales are in minutes. Can i use the Format(365\1440) somehow or is there a better method?

Comment: `hours = minutes / 60` ?

Comment: Where should i try to add that in the code? Sorry for all the questions.

Comment: In the same place? `Dim postCureOvenSumHours = ListBox1.SelectedItems.OfType(Of DataRowView).Where(Function(o) o("OperationsName").ToString() = "POST CURE/OVEN").Sum(Function(o) CType(o("OperationsTime"), Double)) / 60`. That is the sum in hours. Now assign it to a label text, a simple way would be `Label10.Text = postCureOvenSumHours.ToString()`

Comment: Ok sweet thats simple and works well! But its displaying long decimal values like 16.283333333333. Can i format it down?

Comment: You can format it using Double.ToString(format) or String.Format(format, args), see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings

Comment: Is it possible to make it so the items in listbox1 can be selected more than once?

Comment: Sure but that is outside the scope of the question `Trying to get SUM of ListBox selected items from local DataTable into a Label`